# Magento 2 accordion in onestepcheckout does not works

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, widgets

I have add accordion widget to Onestep Checkout following this guide http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html but it does not works

```
    <div id="shipping" class="checkout-shipping-address">
    <div class="step-title" data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
             <span>Indirizzo di Spedizione</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkout-step-shipping"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <!-- ko if: (!quoteIsVirtual) -->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        <!--/ko-->

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('address-list') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('address-list-additional-addresses') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->

        <!-- Address form pop up -->
        <!-- ko if: (!isFormInline) -->
        <button type="button"
                data-bind="click: showFormPopUp, visible: !isNewAddressAdded()"
                class="action action-show-popup">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'New Address'"></span></button>
        <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" data-bind="visible: isFormPopUpVisible()">
            <!-- ko template: 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/address/shipping/form' --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-form') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->

        <!-- Inline address form -->
        <!-- ko if: (isFormInline) -->
        <!-- ko template: 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/address/shipping/form' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: (!isCustomerLoggedIn() && !quoteIsVirtual) -->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
                <!-- ko template: 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/address/billing/create' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        <!--/ko-->

        <div class="mp-clear"></div>

        <!-- ko scope: 'checkout.steps.shipping-step.billingAddress' -->
            <!-- ko template: 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/address/billing/checkbox' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->

        <div class="mp-clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
        require([
            'jquery',
            'accordion'], function ($) {
            $("#shipping").accordion();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your issue is, do you have any console errors?

Try replacing your JS with this:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'accordion',
    'domReady!'], function ($, accordion, doc) {
            $("#shipping").accordion();
});
```

This will ensure it's only initialised once the dom is ready.

Comment: thanks a lot but it does not works anymore. No console errors

Comment: Is your code definitely being rendered, if you add a console log above the require call does it show?

Comment: no console does not print log. really strange

Comment: It sounds like your code may be cached, have you tried deploying static content again, clearing Magento and your browser cache.

Comment: i'm working on dev mode script is correctly printed in html and updated. another strange thing is that also a requirejs custom script in javascript does not work but if i copy and past it on console it works fine. also tried with domReady! on define